Spring Boot controller tests fails java.lang.IllegalStateException : Could not load TestContextBootstrapper
My spring boot applications controller tests fail on the java.lang.IllegalStateException : Could not load TestContextBootstrapper [class org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootStrapper]. Specify @BootstrapWith's 'value' attribute or make the default bootstrapper class available.
after I upgrade the spring boot version from 2.7.x to 3.2.3
This issue is happening after spring boot version upgrade to 3.2.3 from 2.7.x

Generally this comes from trying to outsmart the Spring Boot starter dependency management. This is done by adding conflicting dependencies or select some random modules from a spring portolio project to be added with a specific version. Things like this hinder a smooth upgrade path.
